# How to change project page name?

Tags: application-development, launchpad, quickly

Hi I am taking part in the app showdown but I made a typo on my project while creating it. Can I change this in such a way that the page is changed too? My app name is liberedit however my typo resulted in libereedit, so if possible I would like to change that. I did manage to change its display name correctly just not its page name though, but if possible I'd like to get the project page link right too.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use the `quickly configure lp-project <your project>` command to correct the Launchpad project Quickly will talk to
- However, if you made a typo in the name of the app, I'd suggest to recreate the local Quickly project from scratch with the `quickly create` command, which is going to be easier. Otherwise, you'll have to search and replace the name in all text files in your project.
- You can change the name of the https://launchpad.net/libereedit project in Launchpad. Simply use the 'Administer' link. Or you can do it with this direct link: https://launchpad.net/libereedit/+admin

Comment: You can't rename a project on LP unless you are an admin. [(Relevant bug report)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/917074)

Comment: Thanks @jokerdino, I wasn't aware of the bug. I've fixed the package name for him, then.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you very much! I really appreciate that, apologies for the delay in checking this page, work was busy.